# Typescript own module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am currently learning TypeScript and trying to define my own types. I am currently using .d.ts files to declare my types.

I created a file `./src/typings/git-types.d.ts`:

```
declare module "git-types" {
    export interface GitRepoListItem {
        repoName: string;
        repoPath: string;
    }

    export interface GitReturnObject {
        value: any;
        errorCode: GitErrorCode;
    }

    export enum GitErrorCode {
        UnknownError = 1,
        GitNotFound = 2,
        NoValidPathGiven = 3,
        LocalChangesPreventCheckout = 4,
        LocalChangesPreventPull = 5
    }

    export interface GitCommit {
        hash: string;
        author: string;
        commitDate: string;
        commitTime: string;
        commitMessage: string;
    }
}
```

Now i try to import this module in order to use my types in another file `CommitHistory.ts`:

```
import { GitCommit } from "git-types";

class CommitHistory {
    commitList: GitCommit[] = [];

    ...
}
```

But when i try to run my code, the compiler fails and gives me the following error:
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'git-types' in './src/CommitHistory.ts`

As you can see in my `tsconfig.json`-file the whole "src"-folder is included:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

How do I have to declare the module in order to use my types?

Comment: `d.ts` files are generated by the typescript compiler from your `.ts` files. You wouldn't import a `d.ts` file, these are used by the compiler to tell it what types apply to whatever module you've `import`ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Do not declare your typings as if they came from a global module

In `src/typings/git-types.d.ts`, it's unnecessary to write `declare module "git-types"`. Just export your types:

```
// src/typings/git-types.d.ts
export interface GitRepoListItem {
    repoName: string;
    repoPath: string;
}
// …
```

Then, these types can be imported with a relative path:

```
// src/CommitHistory.ts
import { GitCommit } from "./typings/git-types";
```

## Or, declare types for an existing global modules

If you installed a real npm package `git-types` that contains only JavaScript code and you want to provide types yourself, then your code is fine and should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Exporting the types directly works now for me. However as ethane already said in his comment I had to rename the `git-types.d.ts` file to `git-type.ts`.

Comment: @Psycho No. You don't have to rename. The extension `.d.ts` is better for files that contain only types because the compiler doesn't emit file for these files.